# Difference - Cognition and Recognition

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the exact difference between the two?

Comment: Even though they are closely related in origin, they have very little to do with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recognition?showCookiePolicy=true)

> ***recognition***
>
> noun
>
> 1) the act of recognizing or fact of being recognized
>   2) acceptance or acknowledgment of a claim, duty, fact, truth, etc
>   3) a token of thanks or acknowledgment
>   4) formal acknowledgment of a government or of the independence of a country
>     5) (mainly US & Canadian) an instance of a chairman granting a person the right to speak in a deliberative body, debate, etc

Also according to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cognition?showCookiePolicy=true)

> ***cognition***
>
> noun
>
> 1) the mental act or process by which knowledge is acquired, including perception, intuition, and reasoning
>       2) the knowledge that results from such an act or process

So you can think of cognition as a process of acquiring knowledge and recognition as the process of acknowledging a fact.

With a touch of humor, for example, cognition would be the process through which you learn what a duck is (and the resulting knowledge that is derived from such process), while recognition would be when afterwards you get pecked at by one, and you think "yes, that is a duck".